# Declare a class in another class in android

Tags: java, android

i want to use a class in another class 
e.g

```
public class storge extends Activity {

    public void save() {
        //
    }
}

public class Startuo extends Activity {
    .
    .
    .
    .
   storge s=new stoge();
   s.save();
}
```

when i run it the program stop immediately!! Do i have to add a permission or something to let it work ??? are there wrong in the declaration or what ?

Comment: You must look at Logcat's error messages in order to find out what the specific problem is.

Comment: If you can provide the error message then we might be able to provide helpful input. As it stands I have no idea why your program is crashing. At a glance, you spelled `storge` wrong when you call `new stoge()` (the 'r' is missing). Further, are these in the same file? I don't believe you can have two public classes defined in the same file.

Comment: What is the point of having embedded activities?

Comment: both classes in the same package, i put try and catch and e.getmessge() print null, there is no mistake in the spelling

Comment: @m7m: There's most certainly a spelling error in the sample you posted, so I'd suggest pasting the relevant portions of your actual code rather than this. I'd also look at the Logcat output to find a stacktrace.

Comment: OK ,i will post my code as an answer , i can not posted her

Comment: I could not post my code

Comment: @m7m: You can edit your question at any time with the provided `edit` link at the bottom of the question, right under the tags.

Comment: eldarerathis: thanks very much for your help ,I found the problem? the problem was the class extends Activity can not be use in other class directly in android ! we can call the Activity class by using Intent . (it is different from the normal way like the code above) thanks very much again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classnames should start upper cases. Also, don't declare two classes in one Java File, use two files.

If you want to use both of this classes as Activitys, they booth need to be added to your Android Manifest.

Last but not least, you don't use an Activity by creating an instance of it. To show it up, you should use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Hi Lukas Knuth , can you explain your answer with more details ,for the above code how can i do that

Comment: Simply put your classes in two different Java files, add both this Activitys to your Android Manifest and use an Intent to go from the first to the second one. I wrote a tutorial on that: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/223914-activities-intents-and-something-on-events/

Comment: but i want to pass an attribute to the save function , can i do that with using  Intent !! How can i pass the attribute

Comment: To pass parameters and stuff like that to another Activity, you can use Extras, which are also shown in the Tutorial.

Comment: thanks very much about this important information ,but can i use the class activity in a class that extends Threats,i try to use this Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Storge.class); but it dose not work !! Are there a way to use a class extends activity in a class dose not extends Activity ! thanks for your help!

Comment: Jeah, there are some problems with the 'getApplicationContext()'-method. If you are in a Activity, simply use 'this'.

Comment: How to call An activity class from non Activity class (class without extends anything) in android?

Comment: You can use something like 'YourActivity.this'.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not the correct way to start one Activity from another. Firstly you must define your Activities in separate class files (.java files).

In Storge.java:

```
public class Storge extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (this.getIntent().getAction().equals("SAVE"))
            save();
    }

    private void save() {
    //
    }
}
```

In Startuo.java :

```
public class Startuo extends Activity {
.
.
.
.
    private void StartStorgeActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Storge.class);
        i.setAction("SAVE");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

In saying that though, I'm not really sure this is the best use for a second Activity. Perhaps you should just define Storge as a POJO instead.

Comment: Did you try Google? POJO - > Plain Old Java Object. It simply means a basic Java class.